# Video capture on Linux?

Tags: linux, video, video-capture, image-capture

We need to capture live video and display *easily* on Linux. We need a cheap card or USB device with a simple API. Anyone want to share some experience?

Comment: Closed, not related to programming? I am asking for an API advice! How is that not related to programming?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [video4linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video4Linux) library.  I've used it with a c++ program and was able to capture webcam frames within about an hour. (Very easy to use and setup)

Answer (score 4):

If you need to program, you're best off using [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org), a multimedia framework under Linux.

Cheese, mentioned by jackbravo, is based on GStreamer, as is [Flumotion](http://www.flumotion.net/), a streaming server I work on.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned, Use dvgrab to capture from a Firewire interface from the camera, then use tools such as ffmpeg (command line) or kino (simple gui video editor) to process the video as needed.  PCI based Firewire cards are relatively inexpensive and easy to find.

Here are some examples:

- continuous capture from firewire, autosplit every couple of minutes

  ```
  dvgrab --size 500 --autosplit <filename>
  ```
- watch the camera live

  ```
  dvgrab - | mplayer -
  ```

Be aware that some recent distros (e.g. Fedora8) are using new but half-baked firewire drivers.  However, Ubuntu works great.

Comment: Does this work with webcams? I get `no camera found` on my laptop, and `-V` option throws `Error: v4l2reader.cc:66: In function "virtual bool v4l2Reader::Open()": "m_fd = open( m_device, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK, 0 )" evaluated to -1`

Comment: `--input /dev/video0` turns the cam on but I get `"Waiting for dv"` error

Answer (score 2):

There are "sealed" camera solutions out there with mini-webservers and an ethernet port on the back. Just plug it in to the network, set its IP, and open up a browser... in linux or wherever

If you want to **capture** in linux, I once had a cheap webcam capturing single frames in a perl script, which could have been modified for real time - though that was about 10 years ago. Anyway, its possible :-/

Answer (score 1):

There's the [cheese](http://www.gnome.org/projects/cheese/) gnome application. Really simple to use. Not too much features, just video capture.

Answer (score 1):

openCV will allow you to capture individual frames from a camera and save to disk. If you need to then manipulate these to create a video, I would suggest netpbm, a pretty powerful set of command line tools you can use with some shell scripting to make a video or do whatever it is you need.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use Firewire (IEEE1394) cameras, such as most common DV camcorders.  They tend to work really well and give a lot better video than cheap web cams, and there is a plethora of tools in Linux for working with dv video, such as **dvgrab**.

Answer (score 1):

If you use java, [v4l4j](http://v4l4j.googlecode.com)  makes it very simple to capture frames from any V4L device. It also allows you to control the device  from java. I used it with a PTZ webcam (logitech quickam orbit), and I could control usual thigs like brightness, saturation and auto-white balance, but also the tilt and pan of the camera. Very handy !