# Get video stream from webcam in Linux

Tags: linux, video, video-capture

I'm looking for some general way to get video stream from webcam in Linux and then process and show it in a window. The second part seems simple, but I don't know how to deal with the first one.

Is there some API, lib, docs, etc?.. Where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a little of this before, and you're right, the second part is the easy part. You should take a look at this post for some of the commonly used libraries.

[Video capture on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83899/video-capture-on-linux?rq=1)

I would also throw OpenCV on that list, since it helps with both the obtaining and the processing of video streams:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/

http://www.willowgarage.com/pages/software/opencv

Good luck!